# Map Windows DOMAIN\user to user@KERBEROS.REALM in Java

Tags: java, windows, dns, kerberos

I'm writing an application that needs to take logins in the form of `DOMAIN\user`, but then turn around and authenticate to a Kerberos service. I use a JAAS `LoginContext` using the `Krb5LoginModule` for that which seems to expect the user names in `user@KERBEROS.REALM` format. Is there a way to get that mapping programmatically or from a config file? Alternatively, is there a way to get JAAS to accept "Windows-style" user names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Domain\user` is pre Windows 2000. You should really stick to a UPN-style logins. the Kerberos 5 module accepts Kerberos UPNs only. Are you able have the client to send kerberos tickets directly?

You [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214751/696632) answer as a strarting point. Search for the nETBIOSName and you will find the dnsRoot attribute. Make that uppercase and you have your Kerberos realm. Beware that these attributes are not available in the GC but in normal mode only, so you might need to follow referrals.

Comment: I know they're ancient, it's just that users hate typing in "emp012345@REGION.GIANTCORPORATION.TLD" even more than "RGCORP\emp012345", so it will not go away as long as all Windows dialogs accept it.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising - I've now learned that it's called a NetBIOS name (haha, speaking of ancient, NetBIOS turns 30 next year) and that I can probably get it via LDAP.

Comment: Unfortunately MS sticks to still to this relic. DNS does its job very well. If this answer works, please accept.